# XPath C# Search with attribute name to get another attribute

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I'm really new here as is my first question :)

Im developing a web service and I need to get an attribute that is inside other attribute.

The sample XML from that Im working is the following:

```
<definitions xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 
xmlns:tns="urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/codeunit/Prueba" 
targetNamespace="urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/codeunit/Prueba">
<types>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="urn:microsoft-dynamics-
schemas/codeunit/Prueba">
<element name="FuncionPublica">
<complexType>
<sequence/>
</complexType>
</element>
<element name="FuncionPublica_Result">
<complexType>
<sequence/>
</complexType>
</element>
<element name="FuncionParam">
<complexType>
<sequence>
<element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="parametro1" type="int"/>
</sequence>
</complexType>
</element>
<element name="FuncionParam_Result">
<complexType>
<sequence/>
</complexType>
</element>
<element name="FuncionVar">
<complexType>
<sequence>
<element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="num" type="int"/>
</sequence>
</complexType>
</element>
<element name="FuncionVar_Result">
<complexType>
<sequence>
<element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="num" type="int"/>
</sequence>
</complexType>
</element>
<element name="FuncionReturn">
<complexType>
<sequence/>
</complexType>
</element>
<element name="FuncionReturn_Result">
<complexType>
<sequence>
<element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="return_value" type="int"/>
</sequence>
</complexType>
</element>
</schema>
</types>
</definitions>
```

I need to get "definitions/types/schema/element/@name='FuncionParam'" to get inside that node and follow the XPath search.
Once inside that node, I need to navigate throught it to reach "name='parametro1'" and get that attribute value.

I tested the following but not working, always is returning null:

```
var parametroFuncion = doc.XPathSelectElement("//element[@name=" + 
nombreFuncionText + "]/complexType/sequence/element").Attribute("name");
```

I've tested putting namespace with namespacemanager and also returns null. I don't know what I'm wrong.

Any idea or tip to help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll need to specify the namespace of the elements in the XPath. Currently you're looking for elements in the null namespace. You'll need to link the XPath request to a namespace resolver and use the namespace tags defined in the resolver to annotate the names in that namespace in the XPath expression. There is an example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.xml.xpath.extensions.xpathselectelement?view=netframework-4.7#System_Xml_XPath_Extensions_XPathSelectElement_System_Xml_Linq_XNode_System_String_System_Xml_IXmlNamespaceResolver_).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, what is the prefix? I used the namespacemanager previously with no luck, maybe it's the path I'm specifying at the XPathSelectElement?

Comment: You define the prefix: namespace manager and the XPath expression need to match. But the prefix, if any, used in the doc is a different matter: namespace tags are *local*, the URI of the namespace does the matching between the XPath and the document(s) being searched.